# NPE in Java HashSet.isEmpty()

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception

I got an NPE in java.util.HashSet.isEmpty() on line 191.  I guess, this line just calls isEmpty() on the internal map field.

To my surprise, this field is transient, so after deserialization, it would be null.  But isn't that the purpose of deserializing a set, to get the values back?  To my eyes, being deserialized is the only way this field can be null for a HashSet instance.

Probably, I'm missing something here. Can someone explain?

Java 1.8.0_151 on Linux (3.13.0-61-generic) on platform amd64

Here is the implementation of `HashMap.isEmpty` from the JDK:

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this set contains no elements.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set contains no elements
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return map.isEmpty(); // line 191
}
```

Edit / additional info:

- Unfortunately, I'm not able to give a minimal example demonstrating the problem. It occurs during a regression test of a complex system running for hours. So, I have no knowledge or control about what happens to this set. Also, the problem is nondeterministic, meaning we see it once in a while but not every time
- I could well provide a snippet of our code which calls `isEmpty()`. But the NPE occurs in the library, so that this method was obviously called on an existing instance, i.e, not on `null`. Therefore, providing this snippet would not help much
- our code is multithreaded. But at first glance, this part has single thread access only
- our code catches and swallows Exception in many places. That could hide the real culprit

Comment: `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)` initializes the backing Map, so it shouldn't be null after deserialization.

Comment: Could you make a short piece of code that demonstrates this issue? So make a new set, write it, and then read it again, followed by a call to `isEmpty()`, this allows us to quickly see the problem

Comment: how about providing a snippet of your code? cause I have no idea what is going on at line 191 (-`

Comment: Maybe your set reference is null.

Comment: At a glance through the JDK source code I cannot spot how this could happen. I was thinking if the object could escape prematurely from the constructor or `readObject`, another thread could call `isEmpty` before `map` was set; but I haven’t seen how this could happen.

Comment: This field should always be set, however, it might not be if it was written in one thread and picked up in another in a thread-unsafe way.

Comment: Correct, @PeterLawrey, but is there a way that another thread could get a reference to the `HashSet` before the constructor or `readObject` sets the field? Or would the Java memory model allow another thread to see the initial `null` even after `readObject` had set the field to non-null?

Comment: Ulrich Scholz, one experiment you might try would be to synchronize access to your `HashSet` to make sure there is no concurrency issue involved, and see of the problem goes away.

Comment: I've also seen infinite loops in `HashMap#get`. The only way these things can happen is if you share these containers between threads without proper synchronization. They can get into all kinds of inconsistent states. Don't do that.

Comment: In addition to deserialization, a second code path that resets `map` is `clone`.

Comment: @Thilo but during `clone()`, it will never be `null`.

Comment: @Holger. I don't see how it could be, either, but that got me thinking: Is `clone` thread-safe? If you pass the clone to another thread, will all fields have been cloned reliably?

Comment: @Holger, Thilo: Could the following be the case: an exception during deserialization / during super.clone(), leaving the HashSet instance in an uninitialized state?

Comment: @OleV.V. correct, unless memory barriers have been used. You can get a reference to the HashSet, have readObject called and still see the null value in a second thread. It depends on how the reference to the set was passed.

Comment: @UlrichScholz usually not, as in the exceptional case, you rarely get a chance to get hands on the incomplete instance. That would require a very complex scenario. As a first step to narrow down the problem, do the duty an replace any exception swallowing code with exception logging (or re-throwing) code. You have to do it anyway. Otherwise, the next problem is waiting around the corner…

Comment: @Holger. I already put that replacement action onto the plate. Let's see if I'm assigned time for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `map` field is not `final`, there is no guarantee to see it in its initialized state when publishing a newly constructed `HashSet` instance improperly in multi-threaded code. Whereas “newly constructed”  means that no other action ensuring memory visibility between the involved threads has happened since the construction, which in principle may be an arbitrary long time.

During object deserialization, the `readObject` method takes care of re-initializing the `map` field and putting back the elements. This is necessary to hide these implementation details from the persistent form. Further, deserialized objects may have a different hash code than they had upon serializing (take the hash code inherited from `java.lang.Object`, for example). So they have to be re-inserted anyway. It’s a general principle of most collections to hide the implementation details and just serialize and deserialize each contained element one after another in dedicated `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.

So a future `HashSet` implementation could be a real hash set, not using a `HashMap` behind the scenes, without affecting serialization compatibility.

Comment: The part about the `hashCode` changing between JVM runs is interesting. If you put anything in that Set that depended on instance identity (probably a bad idea in the first place, but there are some use-cases), this will not have survived a round-trip through the serializer. OTOH, if you changed the "hashCode" implementation of your custom class between restarts (probably another bad idea), the deserializer re-hashing everything will keep it consistent with the new implementation.

Comment: Even within the same runtime, serializing, followed by deserializing implies a copying operation which changes object identities, with only a few exceptions, like `enum` constants and singletons.

Comment: The root cause is concurrent access